# Closure and subbasis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ with a subbasis $S$. Does it then hold that $x \in \overline{A}: \Leftrightarrow \forall s \in S: (x \in s \Rightarrow s \cap A \neq  \emptyset).$ This is certainly true if $S$ is a basis, but I suspect it is wrong for a subbasis, am I right?

Comment: It should still work for a subbasis. Subbasic elements are open in $X$ right? So if $x \in A$ or if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ we have to have $s \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Comment: yes, but the converse implication is the one that is in question here :-)

Comment: Hmm.. well let's take any finite collection of elements $\{s_i \}_{i=1}^n$ such that $x \in s_i$. Then $\cap_{i=1}^n s_i$ is a basis element, and you said the converse is certainly true for basis elements. So it should be true for each $s_i$. Is that believable?

Comment: @graydad $s_i \cap A \ne \varnothing$ for each $i$ does not imply that $A \cap \bigcap_{i=1}^n s_i \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: I was trying to argue the opposite; that $A\cap_{i=1}^n s_i \neq \emptyset$ implies $s_i \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subbasis $S$ for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the collection of all the rays $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a,\infty)$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, let 
\begin{align*}
A = \{0,1\} && x = 1/2.
\end{align*} 
Any ray $R$ containing $x$ contains either $0$ or $1$, i.e. $R \cap A \neq \varnothing$. Yet, $x$ does not belong to $\overline A$.

---

Actually, if you think about it, you have the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space with subbasis $S$.  Then, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $S$ is a basis.
> 2. For every set $A \subset X$ and every point $x \in X$, one has $x \in \overline A$ if and only if every $U \in S$ such that $x \in U$ has $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$.

I think you are already aware of the implication (1) implies (2).

Suppose that (2) holds. We need to show that, given a point $x \in X$ and an open set $U \subset X$ such that $x \in U$, there exists $V \in S$ such that $x \in V \subset U$. Let $A$ be the complement of $U$, which is is closed. Since $x \in U$, we have $x \notin A = \overline A$. Thus, by (2), there exists some $V \in S$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \cap A = \varnothing$. In other words, $V \subset U$, which proves (1).

Comment: Where did the question mention the reals?

Comment: @almagest: If the question had been "Is every topological space countable as a set?" and my answer had been "No, consider the space of real numbers" would it have mattered that the question didn't mention the reals?

Comment: A simpler riposte might have been the tag :), which I have only just noticed!